# Problems with a specific while loop not working correctly

Tags: while-loop

Ive been given this assignment and one question I don't understand what im doing wrong exactly.

Question:
The Computer Science Depatment follows certain criteria when a student learns to program. A number of programming exercises must be worked through. To proceed to the next exercise a student has to obtain a mark of 50% or more and must have completed 5 or more program runs. You are requested to write a program to validate if a student can proceed.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int Programsdone;
    int Result;

    while (Result >= 50 || Programsdone >= 5)
    {
    cout << " Please enter your mark obtained :" << endl;
    cin >> Result;
    Programsdone++;
    }

    cout << "Good! You can now proceed to the next exercises." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The data must be validated with a while loop and must be repeated until Result is greater than or equal to 50 AND the value of Programsdone is greater than or equal to 5.

My problem is i cant seem to get the loop to stop correctly and im hopelessly lost with it.
Any help would be great!

Comment: I think it's `while (Result <= 50 || Programsdone <= 5)`. It makes more sense.

Comment: But still you need to `Programsdone++;` only if result was > 50.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

int Programsdone = 0;
int Result;

while (Programsdone < 5) {
     cout << " Please enter your mark obtained :" << endl;
     cin >> Result;
     if ( Result >=50 ) Programsdone++;
}

cout << "Good! You can now proceed to the next exercises." << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I think that's what you mean.

Comment: Tried copying your code and it didnt work but after studying your code against my own i managed to correct it and get it working correctly. Thanks for posting this! Helped greatly.

Comment: @Bezuid I didn't test it before posting, my bad :)